# How to call multiple dynamic await in parallel in javascript

Tags: javascript

Taking this [this example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

The parallel example is

```
async function add1(x) {
  var a = resolveAfter2Seconds(20); // return promise
  var b = resolveAfter2Seconds(30); // return promise
  return x + await a + await b;
}
```

What if i have a, b, c, d, and so on that's all dynamic say array

something like this

```
async function add1(x) {
  var arrayOfPromises = [resolveAfter2Seconds(20), resolveAfter2Seconds(30)];
  return x + arrayOrPromises; // i am expecting same result, but it differes.
}
```

So what is the current syntax for array over await.

Edit : The main issue is, what if i have 10, 100, or 100000 promises?  How would you write a0 + a1 +... a10000 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function resolveAfter2Seconds(x) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(x);
    }, 2000);
  });
}

async function add1(x) {
  var arrayOfPromises = [resolveAfter2Seconds(20), resolveAfter2Seconds(30), resolveAfter2Seconds(40)];
  return x + (await Promise.all(arrayOfPromises)).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
}

async function add2(x) {
  var a = resolveAfter2Seconds(20); // return promise
  var b = resolveAfter2Seconds(30); // return promise
  return x + await a + await b;
}

add1(10).then(v => {
  console.log('add1', v);  // prints 100 after 2 seconds.
});

add2(10).then(v => {
  console.log('add2', v);  // prints 60 after 2 seconds.
});
```

Comment: The main issue is, what if i have 10, 100, or 100000 promises?  How would you write a0 + a1 +... a10000 ?

Comment: You don't have to, `.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)` works for every length of array. Check the documentation of `reduce`. I've updated my answer and added a 3rd promise to show you that it still works :)

Answer (score 0):

Extending Erazihels answer to return the right value:

```
async function add1(x) {
  var arrayOfPromises = [resolveAfter2Seconds(20), resolveAfter2Seconds(30)];
  return x + (await Promise.all(arrayOrPromises)).reduce((a,b)=>a+b,0); 
}
```

or:

```
async function add1(x) {
  [a,b] = await Promise.all([resolveAfter2Seconds(20), resolveAfter2Seconds(30)]);
  return x + a +b; 
}
```

Comment: The main issue is, what if i have 10, 100, or 100000 promises?  How would you write a0 + a1 +... a10000 ?

Comment: @codeofnode like the upper. Promise.all resolves to an array of results, you can apply all Array.prototype methods like map reduce forEach etc on it.